# eclipse startup error code 1

Tags: java, eclipse

I was using eclipse for quite some time without any issues. I installed few programs over last few days and one of them screwed up something. Now I see exactly same error log mentioned in this post.
[Eclipse startup Error code=1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333874/eclipse-startup-error-code-1).

My eclipse.ini file is also same as mentioned in the above post.

So, I tried the solution mentioned in the post by setting the path to 64 bit javaw.exe. But that does not seem to solve my problem. I still see javaw.exe being picked from windows\system32. I updated my PATH variable but that also does not seem to help. Does any one know what could be a problem.

I am using Win7-64 bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the -vm parameter in eclipse.ini but point to the java-bin directory instead of javaw.exe, like this (don't forget the line break between vm and the path):

```
-vm
D:/Java/Jdk16_24/bin
```

Comment: I recommend always explicitly setting the JVM to use on the Windows platform due to this problem.

Comment: @Daniel/Steve: It does remove the error. However, it does not start eclipse and crashes. I have attached the crash dump. Can you make out anything. I repent why I decided to use eclipse. I was good with cscope. Error log =http://pastebin.com/EEAruS7L

Comment: You are using a 64it Eclipse, aren't you?