# eclipse not starting

Tags: eclipse

When I am trying to start eclipse, I am getting following error window:

```
Java was started but returned exit code=1<br>
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\javaw.exe<br>
-Xms40m<br>
-Xmx384m<br>
-XX:-UseCompressedOops<br>
XMaxPermSize=256m<br>
-jar C:\Eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar<br>
-os win32<br>
-ws win32<br>
-arch x84_64<br>
-showsplash<br>
-launcher C:\Eclipse\eclipse.exe<br>
-name Eclipse<br>
--launcher.library C:\Eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502\eclipse_1406.dll<br>
-startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar<br>
-launcher.overrideVmargs<br>
-Xms40m<br>
-Xmx384m<br>
-XX:-UseCompressedOops<br>
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m<br>
-jar C:\Eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar<br>
```

Background:

OS: Wndows 7 64 bit SP1 
Java: jdk1.7.0_03
Eclipse: eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32-x86_64
Java installation folder: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;D:\Nitin Personal\Softwares\;C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

Following is the contents of eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
openFile
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.defaultAction
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333874/eclipse-startup-error-code-1 ?

Comment: In my case, this error message was caused by a typo'd argument in the -vmargs parameter. Hope this helps someone else fix the issue.

Answer (score 13):

I faced the same problem and it was solved by changing the value of `-Xmx` to a lower value in `eclipse.ini.`

**The old configuration was:**

```
-vm C:/your_appication/jvm/jvm160_32/jre/bin/javaw.exe -vmargs -Xms128m -Xmx1024m
```

**The new configuration is:**

```
-vm C:/your_appication/jvm/jvm160_32/jre/bin/javaw.exe -vmargs -Xms128m -Xmx256m
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this problem by removing the javaw.exe. Mine was in C:/Windows/system32/javaw.exe

Comment: I had the same issue. I also had to add the path to the jvm bin folder (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin` in my case) to my system `%PATH%` variable.

Answer (score 2):

On the command prompt, call

eclipse -clean

This will launch the eclipse successfully. It worked for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, so this won't "launch the eclipse succesfully".

Answer (score 1):

Is that the default eclipse.ini, or was it edited?  "openFile" should be on the line after "--launcher.defaultAction"

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the .ini

`-vm`

`c:/apps/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll` if that doesn't help then check and see you have the right eclipse downloaded (32/64bit) Reinstall JDK and JRE to the latest versions see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you do not mix up 64bit Java runtime with 32bit eclipse IDE (or vice versa).
this once caused a similar problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to try lowering the value specified for -Xmx.

I ran into the same error when starting Eclipse Helios on a Windows XP machine (so, both 32-bit OS and 32-bit JDK).  I hadn't changed any configuration on my machine in a while, so I was stumped.

The only difference was that I connected to the machine via RDP.  I believe doing this causes Windows to load some additional DLLs in locations that limit the available contiguous memory.  In my case, I am consistently able to start up the JVM -Xmx1280m when I am sitting in front of the machine, but I can only manage -Xmx1024m when connected via RDP.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\javaw.exe

Answer (score 0):

As per [Eclipse Wiki - eclipse.ini vm_value (windows example)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value%3a_Windows_Example)

> This might not work on all systems. If you encounter "Java was started but returned exit code=1" error while starting the eclipse, modify the -vm argument to point to jvm.dll

So in your case it would be

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
```

Also note that

> The -vm option must occur before the -vmargs option, since everything after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM

I'm running successfully with -Xmx1024m

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem regularly - but only the 2nd time that I launched Eclipse without having rebooted Windows.

I am developing for Android and fixed the problem by making sure that my testing device was not connected via USB when starting Eclipse the 2nd and subsequent times.

Answer (score 0):

-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\javaw.exe is for 32-bit

If you have downloaded 64-bit eclipse install, download JDK1.7 which will by default get installed under C:\Program Files\Java.

Change the -vm argument in the eclipse.ini file pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe.

Your issue should be resolved with this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing all Java components from my Win7 PC and reinstalling "Java SE Runtime Environment 7" for 64bit, because my Eclipse installation was also 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Something might went wrong in eclipse-workspace. I had eclipse show only splash-screen at startup and then disappeared (=crashed).

I was able to recover my precious RemoteSystemsExplorer-connections by renaming old workspace. Then start Eclipse, so it will create empty workspace. Then closed eclipse. Copied from old workspace: workspace3.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.rse.core folder to new workspace folder.

Answer (score 0):

All responses indicate that this issue could be based on your eclipse configuration or java.
I think there should be some kind of log or pop up to let the user know why the IDE is unable to launch.
In my case, restarting the computer resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding the below lines

-vm 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\javaw.exe

This line was not present in my jbdevstudio.ini file.

I think the problem occured because I had copied the 'Java' folder from C: to D:, hence now there were two javaw.exe present in my system.

Note:- Please add them in two lines as given above.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of the above but nothing worked .Finally i re Installed my Java updates it worked

Answer (score 0):

Just changed

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 to 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by adding below line to eclipse.ini file in my case

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

i've fixed it by uninstalling all java components and re-installing the jdk .