# Eclipse error when program start

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse isn't starting, it show this message, i've already download other versions, reinstalled jre. but still showing that message.

[image: that is what happen]

Any idea of how i can fix that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333874/eclipse-startup-error-code-1

Comment: take a look at this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to specify the right JVM in your `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.5\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

Check [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to edit the eclipse.ini especially pay attention to `-vm`. The path given there must point to your jre's `javaw.exe`.

> -startup 
> plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
>   --launcher.library 
> plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
>   -product  
> org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
>   --launcher.defaultAction 
> openFile
>   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 
> 256M
>   -showsplash
>  org.eclipse.platform
>   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 
> 256m
>   --launcher.defaultAction 
> openFile
>   --launcher.appendVmargs
>   -vm 
> C:/java/jre7/bin/javaw.exe
>   -vmargs
>   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
>   -Xms40m
>   -Xmx512m